# rails authlogic - What is the model password field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, passwords, authlogic, seed

I know my database field name (similar to "pass_hashed") but when I try to use a name like password and password_confirmation to create some seeds records as I have done with other apps (where those fields are used to create the encrypted field) those fields are not recognized so
 `User.create(:username => 'Standard', :admin_flag => false, :email => 'junk2@snap2web.com', :password => 'test123', :password_confirmation => 'test123')`
 does not work,  I get unknown attribute password (same with password_confirmation). I am using authLogic with Rails 2.3.8 on ubuntu

Comment: You may need to set attr_accessible on the :password/etc. field if you're doing mass-assignment.

Comment: Good thought Dave.  In my case I had that. Answer was lib (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the right location / file to change -

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/authlogic-2.1.6/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/password.rb
```

I also removed the authlogic gem for rails 3 (my rails 3 projects use Devise anyway right now).
I also make sure the gem file specified the rails2 version (2.1.6) for authlogic which it wasn't (it initially had no version info for authlogic).